# How to get the size <input type = "file">?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote the code to create an tag when I click the Add Attachment button.

And, I have the following code.

```
        <input type="file" name="fileup['+idx+']" id="fileup['+idx+']">

        <input class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" value="fileSizeCheck" onclick="fileSizeCheck('+idx+')" />


            function fileSizeCheck(idx)
            {
                var getName = $('input[id="fileup['+idx+']"]').val();
                var extension = getName.split(".").pop().toLowerCase();

                var i = getName.files[idx].size;
                alert(i);
            }
```

However, this code generates an error.

error code is : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`

getName contains the file name of the selected file.

The extension gets the extension of the selected file.

Here I have a question.

Getting the name of the file succeeded, but I did not know how to get the size of the file.

How can I get the size value of the selected file with my code?

As a script beginner, I do not know much. Your comments are valuable. Please tell me your opinion.

Comment: Well you're trying to find the `input` by ID, yet your input tags don't have IDs.

Comment: I have edited the article. Please confirm. @Utkanos

Comment: you are passing `1` to `idx` , not clear what is in the `idx` you should use `this.files[0].size` or `element.files[0].size`

Comment: Your code doesn't even include the `<input type="file">`...

Comment: I have edited the article. Please confirm @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: Please take a look at [this JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AmitKB/5bk4bgod/1/), hope code is self explains the cause of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure js approach

```js
document.getElementById("myFile").onchange = findSize;

function findSize(){
    var inputTag = document.getElementById("myFile");
    if ('files' in inputTag) {         
      for (var i = 0; i < inputTag.files.length; i++) {        
        var file = inputTag.files[i];        
        console.log(file.size + " bytes");
    }     
}
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="myFile">
```

Comment: I solved it with your help.  Can you give me a code review?

Comment: For every input element of type "file" there are set of standard objects available; One of them is 'files' which is what I have used; from this object one can get the size of the file.

for details of other objects, please verify this link https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_fileupload.asp

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
$('#uploadFile').bind('change', function() {
  alert(this.files[0].size);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" />
```

Comment: Yes. But a little different.

Comment: different like?

Comment: How do I override the idx value based on the way you write when you need to pass the idx value when you click?

Comment: I have multiple <input type = "file"> s. Therefore, the values ​​I have chosen in files [] are not files [0], and the values ​​I have chosen should be contained in files []. I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

I thought your want like this

```js
function fileSizeCheck(idx){
   var getName = $('#fileup'+idx)[0].files;   
   alert("file size is "+getName[0].size);
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="file" name="fileup1" id="fileup1">
<input class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" value="fileSizeCheck" onclick="fileSizeCheck(1)" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="file" name="fileup2" id="fileup2">
<input class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" value="fileSizeCheck" onclick="fileSizeCheck(2)" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I will try that. wait plz

Comment: I have multiple <input type = "file"> s. Therefore, the values ​​I have chosen in files [] are not files [0], and the values ​​I have chosen should be contained in files []. I do not know how to implements.

Comment: I have updated my answer @Seongwon-Choi

Comment: What does files [0] mean?

Comment: `.files` is an array  in that `0`th index is mentioned in [0]